# Trabajar valores concretos JSON de una API

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tras hacer una petición a una API obtengo una respuesta cómo la que se muestra a continuación.

```
{
  "mensaje": "success", 
  "respuesta": [
    {
      "tiempo": 594, 
      "total": 1543419350
    }, 
    {
      "tiempo": 627, 
      "total": 1543425114
    }
  ]
}
```

Esta la se ver en su totalidad empleando `.content`

```
print "Cuerpo de la respuesta:\n",response.content
```

Y se ver simplemente *'respuesta'* mediante

```
decoded = json.loads(response.content)
print decoded['respuesta']
```

Queda algo así:

```
[{u'tiempo': 594, u'total': 1543419350}, {u'tiempo': 627, u'total': 1543425114}]
```

Pero ¿cómo puedo hacer para guardar todos los valores de *'total'* (en este caso 2) en una lista para luego poder trabajar con ellos? Dicho de otra manera, ¿cómo hago para llegar a ellos, sin el resto?

¡Salud!

Comment: Sin saber de Python: `decoded['respuesta']`es un array, podrías recorrerlo y para cada elemento obtener el campo `total`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez has convertido el JSON a un tipo nativo Python, puedes usar las típicas herramientas de este lenguaje para acceder a la información.

En tu caso, el JSON se ha convertido en un diccionario, una de cuyas claves es `'respuesta'` y lo que hay en esa clave es una lista, por lo que perfectamente puedes iterar sobre ella, ya sea en un bucle `for` o mediante una *list comprehension*. Cada elemento de esa lista es a su vez un diccionario, y lo que te interesa de ese diccionario es la clave `total`. Por tanto la siguiente expresión te extraería sólo los datos numéricos asociados a esa clave:

```
tiempos = [ d['total'] for d in decoded['respuesta'] ]
```

La variable `d` va tomando valores de la lista `decoded['respuesta']`. Cada valor es un diccionario del cual extraemos `d['total']`. Al encerrar toda la expresión entre corchetes, creamos una *list comprehension*, que causa que python ejecute ese bucle interno y construya una lista con los resultados. Es decir, obtienes al final la lista de números que buscabas.

```
>>> print(tiempos)
[1543419350, 1543425114]
```

Un detalle, si para la petición a la API usaste la librería `requests`, puedes usar directamente `decoded = response.json()`, sin necesidad de usar `json.loads()`.